# using "like" to compare a string with two wildcards VBA

Tags: vba, wildcard

I am comparing two sheets of data. One on sheet, I have a bunch of strings like this: "Apples - are good (YES)" while on the other sheet, I have strings like this "Apples - YES" . in this scenario, the two strings should be compared as the same. When the original data was compiled, there was no naming standard between the two sources. This means that when im using the "like" function, I need it to handle two separate wildcards because there are two parts of the string that need to be compared. What I have right now:

```
 Dim TorF as Boolean
 TorF = stringToCompare Like subString1 & "*YES*"
```

I know my function as a whole is sound, because previously I was only using one wildcard and simply ignoring any strings that contained "-". However, now I actually have to deal with the extra results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by searching the `substring1` and `"YES"` within your `stringToCompare` and proceed with your code when `True`:

```
If InStr(1, stringToCompare, subString1, vbTextCompare) > 0 And InStr(1, stringToCompare, "YES", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        'your code
End If
```

Comment: this only works with same case scenarios, correct? I was hoping to implement the like function so I could avoid having to manipulate case.

Comment: No, it works when both `substring1` and `"YES"` is within your `stringToCompare`. Is there any other case you would like to consider? I.e., what is the case you want to avoid by using `like`?

Comment: by case I meant upper/lower. The strings are very different since there was no naming standard for both extracts

Comment: So you want your code case sensitive? If you use `vbBinaryCompare` then it is case senstive, if you use `vbTextCompare` then it is not.

Comment: gotcha. i've never used explicits in InStr, only (i.e.,) Instr(source, "a")